# wlst script to check the status of weblogic servers

Tags: wlst

Could you please let me know the wlst script to check the status of weblogic servers?

I know the command to check a particular server but i need the status of all the instances in that environment.

Answer (score 4):

**Navigate to the following location and press Enter:**

C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\common\bin>wlst.cmd

**Then connect to Weblogic Admin Server**
wls:/offline> **connect("Username","Password","Admin console Url")**

**Example**
wls:/offline> **connect("weblogic","Password","localhost:7001")**

Then run following command
wls:/woolworths/serverConfig> **x=ls('Servers',returnMap='true')**

This will return all your servers :

**dr--   AdminServer

dr--   server 1

dr--   server 2

dr--   server 3**

Then run :

wls:/woolworths/serverConfig> **x**

Which will return:

**[AdminServer, server 1, server 2, server 3]**

Then Run
wls:/woolworths/serverConfig> **for i in x: state(i,'Server')**

Which will return :

Current state of "AdminServer" : RUNNING
Current state of "server 1" : RUNNING
Current state of "server 2" : SHUTDOWN
Current state of "server 3" : RUNNING

Hope this helps you ?

Comment: I wrote a script, this is also not staying after calling the .py script from from command promt

Comment: nmConnect(');
connect();

domainConfig()
serverList=cmo.getServers();
domainRuntime()
cd('/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/')

for server in serverList:
     name=server.getName()
     cd(name)
     serverState=cmo.getState()
     if serverState=='SHUTDOWN':
        print '**** Shutdown Servers ****'
        print 'Server *****'+ name +'***** State *****'+serverState
        break 
     print 'Server *****'+ name +'***** State *****'+serverState
     cd('..')

Comment: please let me know what should i add in this script so that it holds the screen

Comment: try adding "pause" at the end of the script that should keep the cmd window open.